# Given a normal vector, what information can you extract?

Tags: vectors, 3d, orthogonality, plane-geometry

In my textbook, $n = 3i +2j + 6k$ which lies on the $y$-axis. Can you explain how is that because I understand that it should go $3$ units on $x$ then $2$ on $y$ then $6$ on $z$ which is not on the $y$-axis??

Comment: No we cannot explain how that is, because it isn't. You are correct that this is not on the Y axis. But I strongly suspect that you are incorrect about your book saying so. It likely says something else that you misinterpreted. (Maybe it is talking about projecting this vector onto the Y axis?)

Comment: Re-read the problem , I don't think you understood the problem properly.

Comment: it's a picture.. is there a way to post it here

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1r1TFC-C8m_ODlxSkJFX056NVk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: n is a direction vector

Comment: but it says normal vector which is used with planes!! could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there's only one normal vector to a plane but it can take different places. so the picture is correct and the normal vector was made on the Y axis to make calculations easier. The result would be the same for my problem even if the normal vector changes its position.